# Cartesian product of a set with another Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $A = \{a, b, c, d\}$
>
> $C = \{ (1,2), (1,3), (2,4) \}$
>
> $A \times C = ?$

Do I calculate this Cartesian product like a regular Cartesian product or are there any specific rules for calculating such an expression?
By the regular way, I mean like

> $A \times C = \{(a, (1,2)), (a, (1,3)), (a, (2,4)), (b, (1,2)), \ldots\}$ and so on

Comment: No specific rule, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. However, the third element is $(a,(2,4))$ in your posting.